# How to play random wav files in Visual Basic remotely from web

Tags: vb.net, audio, random

I am making a program and instead of having the wav files embedded (Program becomes way to big); I decided to upload the songs to my site. The program is a kid's game, once the game ends, I want it to play a random song from the URL. Originally, I used a code to do it from the embedded Resources. This was the code:

```
        Public Sub PlayRandomTrack()
           Randomize()

    Dim trackNum As Integer = CInt(Rnd() * 5 + 0.5)

    Select Case trackNum
        Case 1
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.CallingMonsters, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 2
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.McclainSisters, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 3
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Mendler, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case 4
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Pray, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        Case Else
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.WillowWhip, AudioPlayMode.Background)

    End Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way to just simply put the URL's somewhere instead of an entire new code? If it is a new code that's needed what would it be? I can't find any information on this online.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Dim SongURLs As New List(Of String)
    Dim R As New Random
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        GameOver()
    End Sub
    Sub GameOver()
        PlayRandomInternetSong()
    End Sub
    Sub PlayRandomInternetSong()
        Randomize()
        Dim RandomSongIndex As Integer = R.Next(0, SongURLs.Count)
        PlayOnlineWaveFile(SongURLs(RandomSongIndex))
    End Sub
    Sub PlayOnlineWaveFile(ByVal Address As String)
        Dim WavBytes As Byte()
        Using W As New WebClient
            WavBytes = W.DownloadData(Address)
        End Using
        Using mStream As New MemoryStream(WavBytes, False)
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(mStream, AudioPlayMode.Background)
        End Using
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/adios.wav")
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/excellent.wav")
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/failure1.wav")
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/Austin_Powers_groovy.wav")
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/american_pie_bless_net.wav")
        SongURLs.Add("http://www.villagegeek.com/downloads/webwavs/BluesBros_106miles.wav")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm not going to be using a button. The trigger will be that the game is over. Which I already know how to do, but how would this play random files from the internet?

Comment: This shows you how to play a wave file that is online. It's up to you to know what URL you want to download. You could store your URL's in a list(Of String) and create a randomnumber generator whos exclusive upperbound was the upperbound of your list(of string), then just use the random number generated to select the item at that index, and feed it to the function provided...